# WPF Toggle visibility of UIElements in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, uielement

I have a `DataTemplate` defined as follows

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PasswordViewerTemplate">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PasswordChar, ElementName=this}"
               Visibility="Visible" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding PasswordText}"
             Visibility="Collapsed" />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I want to be able to toggle visibilities of the `TextBlock` and the `TextBox` each time the user clicks on the `StackPanel`. I tried setting a `MouseLeftButtonUp` event handler on the `StackPanel` but this throws an exception

> `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Is there another way to achieve this? Maybe in XAML itself using triggers?

Also, this might be relevant. The above template is one of two that is applied to a `ListBox` by a template selector. The `ListBox` itself is within a `Grid` and both templates are defined within the `Grid.Resources` section.

**EDIT 1**
I tried setting the event as follows

```
<StackPanel MouseLeftButtonUp="OnPasswordViewerMouseLeftButtonUp">
...
</StackPanel>
```

```
private void OnPasswordViewerMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  var sp = sender as StackPanel;
  if( ( sp == null ) || ( sp.Children.Count != 2 ) ) {
    return;
  }

  var passwordText = sp.Children[0] as TextBlock;
  var plainText = sp.Children[1] as TextBox;
  if( ( passwordText == null ) || ( plainText == null ) ) {
    return;
  }

  passwordText.Visibility = ( passwordText.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ) ? 
    Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
  plainText.Visibility = ( plainText.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ) ?
    Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to display a `TextBox` instead of a `TextBlock` for the selected item?

Comment: @Meleak I want the toggle the visibilities of the `TextBlock` and the `TextBox` each time the user clicks on the `StackPanel`.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, then the `StackPanel` is in the `ItemTemplate` of a `ListBoxItem` so the `TextBlock` will decide the size of the `StackPanel`. This means that you can never click on the `StackPanel` directly since the `TextBlock` will lay on top of it unless you set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` in `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: What do you want to happend if the `TextBox` is visible and you click it? Should that toggle visibility as well?

Comment: @Meleak Yes, the `TextBlock` completely covers the `StackPanel`, but shouldn't the click event bubble up to the `StackPanel` anyway? If you look at the XAML above, initially TextBlock is visible, TextBox is not. First click -> TextBlock collapsed, TextBox visible. Second click -> TextBlock visible, TextBox collapsed. And so on ...

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is to bind visibility of the `TextBox` and `TextBlock` to properties of the class which is used as `DataContext` for the `StackPanel`. Here is a sample implementation:

**Xaml code:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PasswordViewerTemplate">
            <StackPanel PreviewMouseUp="StackPanel_PreviewMouseUp">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PasswordChar}"
           Visibility="{Binding Path=TextBlockVisibility}" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PasswordText}"
         Visibility="{Binding Path=TextBoxVisibility}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PasswordViewerTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
</Grid>
```

**And C# code:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<Some> items = new ObservableCollection<Some>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new Some(string.Format("passwordChar {0}", i + 1), string.Format("passwordText {0}", i + 1), Visibility.Visible, Visibility.Collapsed));
        }
        this.lbox.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    private void StackPanel_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Some some = (sender as StackPanel).DataContext as Some;
        some.TextBlockVisibility = ToggleVisibility(some.TextBlockVisibility);
        some.TextBoxVisibility = ToggleVisibility(some.TextBoxVisibility);
    }
    private Visibility ToggleVisibility(Visibility visibility)
    {
        return visibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
public class Some:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _passwordChar;
    private string _passwordText;
    private Visibility _textBlockVisibility, _textBoxVisibility;

    public string PasswordChar { get { return this._passwordChar; } set { this._passwordChar = value; } }
    public string PasswordText { get { return this._passwordText; } set { this._passwordText = value; } }
    public Visibility TextBlockVisibility 
    { 
        get { return this._textBlockVisibility; } 
        set 
        { 
            this._textBlockVisibility = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TextBlockVisibility");
        }

    }
    public Visibility TextBoxVisibility 
    { 
        get { return this._textBoxVisibility; }
        set 
        { 
            this._textBoxVisibility = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TextBoxVisibility");
        }
    }

    public Some(string passwordChar, string passwordText, Visibility textBlockVisibility, Visibility textBoxVisibility)
    {
        this._passwordChar = passwordChar;
        this._passwordText = passwordText;
        this._textBlockVisibility = textBlockVisibility;
        this._textBoxVisibility = textBoxVisibility;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you bind the item's visibility in your view model?

an Example.

```
<Textblock Test="{Binding passwordText,ElementName=This}" Visibility="{Binding passwordTextVisibility}"/>
```

in your ViewModel say

```
public Visibility passwordTextVisibility
{
 getters and setters here
}
```

and on your mouse event, you would need some sort of routed event inside the stack panel. an example:

inside the stack panel you would need mouse. whatever you need. read a little about routed events

Example. if `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` does not work.

```
<StackPanel Mouse.MouseUp="MouseButtonUpEventHandler"/>
```

in the view model

```
public void MouseButtonUpEventHandler (RoutedEvent e)
{
//logic here to check if it's left mouse if it is then set visibility
}
```

}

Comment: And how would I tie this to the mouse click event?

Comment: I think there is a PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp you can use

Comment: and when your mouseLeftbutton comes up, then you set the visibility

Comment: heres a good link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.previewmouseup.aspx

Comment: Setting an event handler for PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp throws the same exception (same for Mouse.PreviewMouseUp). Anyway, if I need to set an event handler I can just get the StackPanel, its Children and then toggle the Visibility in code rather than messing with the view model.

Comment: I've always learned its a bad idea to do it in the code behind, but toggling the visibility isn't bad. are you sure you are writing the events correctly? post more code i'll ty to help you the best i can

Comment: Can you try Mouse.MouseUp? inside the xaml rather using MouseLeftButtonUp

Comment: and do 

private void ButtonOkClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

Mouse mouseUp= (Mouse) sender;
//logic

}

Comment: Same thing, I think there's another underlying issue here with the DataTemplate that prevents me from setting any event handler. Maybe because it is being selected by a DataTemplateSelector ...